# Can we use to-infinitive after 'have trouble'?

Tags: infinitives, present-participles

Given the example:

> I have trouble **speaking** English.

Can we use both present participle (speaking) and to-infinitive (to speak) after *have trouble*?
If both are allowed, do the two have the same meaning or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you may not use the *to*-infinitive after *to have trouble*.  You may only use the *-ing* form.  You can think of it as an abbreviated version of this:

> I have trouble **with** speaking English.

And for the most part, *to*-infinitives make poor objects of prepositions; for that were gerunds invented.

Comment: The _with_ is optional. _I have trouble speaking English_ is fine, as is _I always have trouble starting the car in January, She had trouble explaining it to them,_ and _I don't know why you have trouble doing that._

Comment: @JohnLawler I hope I did not accidentally imply that with *with* is mandatory. I just find it easier to make sense of if I think of it as being there.

Answer (score 0):

In many other languages, what might usually be translated as **"to *verb*"** in English is in fact one word – **parler**, **sprechen**, **говорить** etc. – whilst in English they are two words, and so usage naturally evolved differently. The fact that the **verbal noun** is identical to the infinitive in French, German, Russian etc., but the present participle in English shows that they are thought of differently in these languages. Cases are arbitrarily split in English between the infinitive and the verbal noun, which are identical when translated into most other languages. There are cases, e.g. "I want **to speak**", where **to** is used as a nonce to form the infinitive, where that form is used. But there are also cases where the **verbal noun**, i.e. **speaking**, e.g. **I have trouble *speaking* English**, is idiomatic. It really depends on the verb, and has developed through usage, rather than through strict rules.